# ant build fails when on mapped drive with VPN connection

Tags: java, ant, vpn, ant-contrib, mapped-drive

I have the following part in one of my build xmls. - called "common.xml"
This comes from the common library in the company, so many projects share this same construct.

```
<target name="init.compile.copy.sources">
 <if>
  <isreference refid="compile.copy.sources"/>
  <then>
    <property name="compile.copy.sources" value="1"/>
  </then>
</if>
</target>
```

And my build scripts with ant look just fine when on the PC in the office.  The particular project is named "eMyproj", and sits in a directory c:\developer\projects\myProject.  Again it works fine when in the office.

From home, I am connected with VPN and mapped my home drive (B:) to the network folder from my office PC.  And the build script do not work.  SOme other script do work, so my ant ant java home at home PC are set correctly, however in one of the scripts I get this error:

```
B:\eMyproj\trunk\.buildsys\common.xml:63: Problem: failed to create task
 or type if
 Cause: The name is undefined.
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem?  I am not to change anything in the build scripts, since it is working while on the office PC. However, when on network mapped drive, it fails.  Must be the path somewhere.. but I looked at all I can imagine.

Comment: It seems to be the network path issue. Try running the common.xml directly. If not works, then create a sample build file place it in your mapped drive and try to access that.

Comment: You have not included the ant-contrib jar. The "if" task is not part of standard ANT.

Comment: Thanks, Mark .. that is right.  I did not include it.  The reason being, I am "accessing" the existing project via VPN.  Simply running using my home PC processor - the project is original and works on a native machine, and not on just one. I am not writing ANYTHING, and hence, am not adding anything.  With that said, it is probably NOT included in the original project, but it seems to be working without it.  All the access and paths are relative..  So.. I am guessing is is somehow is being accessed from inside of the included scripts .. how can I find out ?